# Docker networks: How to get container1 to communicate with server in container2

Tags: docker, apache, networking, server, bridge

I have 2 containers on a docker bridge network. One of them has an apache server that i am using as a reverse proxy to forward user to server on another container. The other container contains a server that is listening on port 8081. I have verified both containers are on the same network and when i log into an interactive shell on each container i tested successfully that i am able to ping the other container.
The problem is, is that when i am logged into the container with the apache server, i am not able to ping the actual server in the other container.

the ip address of container with server is 172.17.0.2

How i create the docker network

```
docker network create -d bridge jakeypoo
```

How i start the containers

```
docker container run -p 8080:8080 --network="jakeypoo" --
name="idpproxy" idpproxy:latest

docker run -p 8081:8080 --name geoserver --network="jakeypoo" geoserver:1.1.0
```

wouldn't the uri to reach out to the server be

```
http://172.17.0.2:8081/
```

?

PS: I am sure more information will be needed and i am new to stack overflow and will happily answer any other questions i can.

Comment: Can you also please add to the question description how do you start your containers and how do you configure container networks, as well as error message when pinging or trying to reach with curl?

Comment: @m19v I just updated the post with the information you requested. I am not using curl, i am just logging into the container and using ping

Comment: I have started two nginx servers in a way how you started your container and network. I can ping from both container each other. This means, container network created correctly and containers connected to it and can talk with each other. Can you please make sure to get the correct IP of containers with ```docker network inspect <name-of-network>``` and ping with only IPs, e.g. ```ping 172.17.0.2```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you started the two containers on the same `--network`, you can use their `--name` as hostnames to talk to each other.  If the service inside the second container is listening on port 8080, use that port number.  Remappings with `docker run -p` options are ignored, and you don't need a `-p` option to communicate between containers.

In your Apache config, you'd set up something like

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://geoserver:8080/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://geoserver:8080/"
```

It's not usually useful to look up the container-private IP addresses: they will change whenever you recreate the container, and in most environments they can't be used outside of Docker (and inside of Docker the name-based lookup is easier).

(Were you to run this under Docker Compose, it automatically creates a network for you, and each service is accessible under its Compose service name.  You do not need to manually set `networks:` or `container_name:` options, and like the `docker run -p` option, Compose `ports:` are not required and are ignored if present.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this further.)

Comment: Wow thankyou for the helpful post, I will try this when I login. Though I'm not sure how using the hostname will work if private IP it represents doesn't because I did try port 8080. I'll let you know if that works

Comment: The two things to check on the service you're trying to connect to (application-level configuration, not Docker-specific) are (a) what port number is the service itself listening on, and (b) is the service listening on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address?  Use that port number (again, `docker run -p` isn't used or required).  If the service is listening on 127.0.0.1 it won't be reachable from outside its container at all.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this can be the reason.

when you log into one of the container that container do not know anything about the other container network. when you ping, that container think you are try to ping a service inside that container.

Try to use docker compose if you can use it in your context. Refer this link:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: the containers are on the same network bridge network and can communicate with each other, but I just can't communicate with the actual server running on the container from the other container

Comment: Something same was faced by me.Then What I did was I used docker compose. Then it worked fine.

Comment: If containers are in same network, servers inside containers are in different networks.

Comment: ok, I will do some reading on docker compose. Thanks!